# MusicKit to play music from music library, along with seek forward and backward

Tags: ios, ios11, playback, forward

With iOS 11, MusicKit on iOS lets users play Apple Music and their local music library natively from your apps and games.

As per Apple, MusicKit lets users play Apple Music and their local music library natively from your apps and games. When a user provides permission to their Apple Music account, your app can create playlists, add songs to their library, and play any of the millions of songs in the Apple Music catalog.

Can we play this music if user has not downloaded music from iTunes through MusicKit.

Also, can it be used to seek forward or backward.

Comment: I can't get the MusicKit to see the local Media Library. The example code doesn't seem to do that, so I'm wondering if the documentation is misleading. I'm suspicious that the MusicKit only access the Apple Music library, that may be locally stored. I don't see any API's to allow access to the normal iTunes based Media Library.

Comment: Hello, @Jas_meet. Have you figured out yet?

Comment: Yes it's done   :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MediaPlayer framework provides features for seek forward and backward

```
  MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer().beginSeekingForward()

  MPMusicPlayerController.systemMusicPlayer().beginSeekingBackward()
```